# Mixing javascript and inline server code

Tags: c#, javascript, client-side, server-side, inline-code

I am trying to do the following:

```
   <script>
      var documentId = %(this).attr('id');

      <% int docId = %>documentId<%;%>

   </script>
```

As you can see, I'm trying to create a new server variable but assign the value of the javascript variable. Or at least have the javascript variable evaluated. (This is a simplied example of the real world problem I'm trying to solve) Is there any way that I can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem:

1. Server-side code is evaluated on the server, **before anything is transmitted to the client**.
2. Client side code (JavaScript) is evaluated in the browser, **after the server has finished transmitting the document**.

After understanding the above statements, you'll see that your current example is technically impossible.

What you will need to do (if your goal is to prevent a page refresh) is send the new data to a script on the server using AJAX.  The script will process the data and respond to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

The server code will get processed first, before the page is ever rendered. So you'd have to use something like AJAX to pass a JavaScript value back to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is your server code that gives the object an @id, the server should already know it at the point of creation. But no, you can't interleave client and server like that - they run disjoint in time and geography

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this because the server variable will have already been calculated and the HTML has been generated by the time the client script runs.

Server Side Code Runs => Generated HTML File Served To Browser => Javascript Code Runs

This process is one-way, so there's not a way to give that variable back without using an Ajax request.

However, if all you need is the id, and the control is a .NET control, you can simply use the myControl.ClientID value.

Answer (score 0):

To send data from browser to server you should use form controls (text field, hidden field, textarea, checkbox, etc.) or ajax. In your case, you can serialize javascript object to a string and pass it to the server via hidden field or XmlHttpRequest.